# Open PDF in new tab, saving file gives wrong file name

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, pdf

There is an Angular 6 app having a feature to download pdf files. It uses REST API from another Spring Boot application to download files.

The requirement is that i need to open pdf file in new tab and while saving it shall have a meaningful name.

I am able to get the file downloaded and open in new tab too. But while saving the file, it takes name from the url.

I tried by opening the file directly from REST API in browser and save it as well as getting blob and open in new window from angular app. Both open the files but while saving they take name from URL.

1. Angular - Open blob in new window
   blob:https://defg.com/89a0396e-994b-43d0-b3e3-aaa95d47db9f
   If i try to download opened file, it suggests to save with name 
   89a0396e-994b-43d0-b3e3-aaa95d47db9f.pdf
   Is there a way to pass or set filename in below approach?

   var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL, "_blank");
2. API - Takes Encrypted name
   https://abcd.com/ws/fileDownload/85C1E5010AFAE309E89534FAC594C9110D74FED4DF78AAA8EE199C78B570FABF8BC6640F0563778DD963
   If i try to download opened file, it suggests to save with correct name for first time, shows string from url as name from second attempt, 85C1E5010AFAE309E89534FAC594C9110D74FED4DF78AAA8EE199C78B570FABF8BC6640F0563778DD963.pdf

Inspected response, headers look good,

Content-Disposition: inline; filename= "test.pdf"

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `filename` in the `Content-Disposition` header is ignored if the disposition is not "attachment".

Comment: Is there a way to use filename and open a pdf in new tab?

Comment: @Pointy You may not be fully correct saying filename will be ignored. But it behaves inconsitently in different browsers.
http://test.greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#inlwithasciifilenamepdf

Comment: I was just going by the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). The RFC is not super-clear, as is typical. In any case as you've seen it can't be trusted to work consistently.

Comment: @NagarajaJB - were you able to find any work-around? I am in the similar situation now

Comment: @KinleyChristian Sorry that its been a long time and as far as I remember, we couldn't fix it.

Comment: @NagarajaJB if you wish to download the document then I have solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68094353/alternatives-to-generate-pdf-document-using-array-buffer-response-of-an-api but the same issue of file name is still there in case file is opened in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `file-saver` library as follow:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
...
awesomeDownloader(url: string, fileName: string) {
  const blobFile = functionsThatGetsTheBlob(url);
  saveAs(blobFile, fileName);
}
...
```

Comment: saveAs(blobFile, fileName); if not a pdf. I have a requirement to open pdf instead of saving the file directly.